# how to pass data from login api to profile api?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, jwt, header

I am a beginner in Nodejs and Mongo dB. I am creating a signup/login system with authentication and also I have to make a profile page. I have built a login API here is the code

```
router.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const usermail = await UserSignup.findOne({email:email});
        const isMatch = bcrypt.compare(password,usermail.password);
        if(isMatch){
            const token = generatetoken(usermail._id)
            res.setHeader('JWT_TOKEN',token);
            // res.status(201).json({
            //     message:"User loged in",
            //     userdetail:{
            //         name:usermail.name,
            //         email:usermail.email,
            //         Phone:usermail.mobilenumber,
            //         Id:usermail._Id
            //     }
            // })
            res.redirect('/api/user/welcome',{useremail:email})
        }
        else{
            res.status(400).send("Invalid Credentials")
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal server error")
    }
})
```

I have redirected the User after logging in to the welcome page.
so In the welcome page I have to display user name email. how can I do that?

```
router.get('/welcome',auth,(req,res)=>{


})
```

what should I write in the welcome API to get information about the logged user?

I have passed information of the user in 2nd argument of redirect is it correct or not because I can not able to access it in the welcome route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `query strings`. Modify you `login` route to redirect to:

```
res.redirect('/api/user/welcome?email=' + email)
```

And that you can access the query in the `welcome` route like so:

```
let email = req.query.email;
```